# Подскажите пожалуйста чем выражены выделенные места + их синтаксическая функция (parte 2)

Tags: cинтаксис

1) *Она всегда рассовывала его письма **куда-нибудь с глаз долой**.*

2) *Он был готов к тому, что его не примут, конечно, **под каким-нибудь вежливым предлогом**, и это помогало ему сохранять спокойствие.*

3) *Она **то и дело** прерывала его рассказ своими вопросами.*

4) *Вместо статуи обезглавленного героя поставили другую, в парадном мундире, без имени, без даты и **без всякого на то основания**, поставили на внушительном пьедестале, …*

5) *Эта книга не имела ничего общего ни с одной, написанных им **когда бы то ни было** ранее.*

Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

Обстоятельства, выраженные фразеологизмами

Comment: ... дорогая Людмила, я не специалист, но в (2) не нахожу ничего фразеологического...

Answer (score 2):

- ***Куда-нибудь с глаз долой*** - обстоятельство,выраженное фразеологизмом.
- ***Под каким-нибудь вежливым предлогом*** - согласованное определение.
- ***то и дело*** - фразеологизм, выраженный обстоятельством.
- ***без всякого на то основания*** - нареч., выраженное обстоятельством
- ***когда бы то ни было*** -   обстоятельство, выраженное наречным фразеологизмом.